# Mysql timezone change on linux after Linux system timezone change

Tags: mysql, linux, datetime, timezone

I have changed my Cent OS timezone to Asia/Calcutta , but the MySQL installed refers to the old time zone that the system had. Do I need to restart MySQL -( its diff for me to bring MySQL down for the time ) to see the effect or theres different conf changes that I need to do in order to see the MySQL timezone same as the system .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to change the time_zone for a MySQL instance at runtime.

There's no need for us to repeat *everything* the MySQL Reference Manual says on this topic. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html  (Be sure you refer to the specific version of MySQL you are running.)

Bottomline... you can accomplish changes to the MySQL time_zone setting without a restart.

If time_zone='SYSTEM', then to change the MySQL server time zone without a restart of the MySQL server, you will need to modify the time_zone variable. For example, to change time_zone to UTC

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+00:00'
```

---

I've not tested the behavior when changing the time zone setting for the Linux OS. All of our MySQL server run as UTC, independent of the OS time zone setting. (Our MySQL instances time_zone is decoupled from the Operating System timezone.)

Without knowing the current settings of the various MySQL system variables related to time zone, or whether you have populated the time zone support tables in the mysql database, I can't provide specific advice.

Note that current connections to the database won't be affected by the changing the value of the global variables. The time_zone setting for a session is established when the session is started. (How this affects you depends on whether your app is using a connection pool, re-using established connections, or whether your app is churning connections.

I suggest you start by referring to the documentation.

And I strongly recommend you *test* your proposed changes in a test environment, before you make changes to a system that you can't restart.